# Getting rid of lines/axis in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, grid, line, axis

How can I get rid of the last two lines (horizontal, vertical) in the chart.
I tried all kind off different methods as below, but those two keep there.
Can anyone point me in the direction where my code is flawed.

The ca.plot coordinates is a method called by Prince for plotting the results of a CA as matplotlib.

```
ax = ca.plot_coordinates(
X=X,
ax=None,
marker = "o",
color='k',
figsize=(32, 18),
x_component=0,
y_component=1,show_row_labels=False,show_col_labels=False,
)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.get_figure().gca().set_title("")
ax.grid(False)

ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

ax.get_figure ()
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library, but my quick analysis of the code shows that these lines are hard-coded:

[`ca.plot_coordinates()`](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/blob/fde67be4c84c558b452ba9feb797f1cdca811f2d/prince/ca.py#L165) calls [`plot.stylize_axis()`](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/blob/fde67be4c84c558b452ba9feb797f1cdca811f2d/prince/plot.py#L13), which in turns draws these two lines whether you want them or not ([L21–22](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/blob/fde67be4c84c558b452ba9feb797f1cdca811f2d/prince/plot.py#L21)):

```py
ax.axhline(y=0, linestyle='-', linewidth=1.2, color=GRAY['dark'], alpha=0.6)
ax.axvline(x=0, linestyle='-', linewidth=1.2, color=GRAY['dark'], alpha=0.6)
```

Thankfully, the artists thus created should be stored in `ax.lines`, so you should be able to remove the first two lines there:

```py
del ax.lines[:2]
```

Comment: You're my hero! I would have never thought of checking the Prince code.
This worked perfectly! Thanks a million.
Need to get more "reputation to upvote you" - but it's recorded!